# Replace function does only replace every second regex match

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to use regex in javascript to put a zero before every number that has exactly one digit.

When i debug the code in the chrome debugger it gives me a strange result where only every second match the zero is put.

My regex

```
"3-3-7-3-9-8-10-5".replace(/(\-|^)(\d)(\-|$)/g, "$10$2$3");
```

And the result i get from this

```
"03-3-07-3-09-8-10-05"
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use word boundaries,

```
(\b\d\b)
```

Replacement string:

```
0$1
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/fN3zU5/11)

```
> "3-3-7-3-9-8-10-5".replace(/(\b\d\b)/g, "0$1")
'03-03-07-03-09-08-10-05'
```

**Explanation:**

- `(` starting point of first Capturing group.
- `\b` Matches between a word character and a non word character.
- `\d` Matches a single digit.
- `\b` Matches between a word character and a non word character.
- `)` End of first Capturing group.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this better lookahead based regex to prefix `0` before every single digit number:

```
"3-3-7-3-9-8-10-5".replace(/\b(\d)\b(?=-|$)/g, "0$1");
//=> "03-03-07-03-09-08-10-05"
```

Reason why you're getting alternate prefixes in your regex:

```
"3-3-7-3-9-8-10-5".replace(/(\-|^)(\d)(\-|$)/g, "$10$2$3");
```

is that rather than looking ahead you're actually matching hyphen after the digit. Once a hyphen has been matched it is not matched again since internal regex pointer has already moved ahead.

Comment: "put a zero before every number that has exactly one digit"

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's question.

Comment: I overlooked that part, its fixed now.

Comment: Avinashs answer did it for me but thank you for the explanation why it only matched every second number.

Answer (score 0):

use a positive lookahead to see the one digit numbers :

```
"3-3-7-3-9-8-10-5".replace(/(?=\b\d\b)/g, "0");
```